# Pygame: Rendered fonts have solid boxes around them

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, render

I have some code that worked fine before I upgraded to Python 3.3 and

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame Pygame for 3.3.

Now, when I run it, I get ugly white squares around the rendered fonts.

[image]

Yick. Anyone else getting this problem, or perhaps have any solutions to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions.  First, try `(255, 255, 255, 0)` for the fourth argument in the `font.render` command.  Second, if that doesn't work, put the color that is behind the text for the fourth argument.  The first probably won't work, but the second definitely will.

## Edit

Actual solution: just set the text surface objects' colorkey to `(255, 255, 255)`.  Simple.

Comment: The fourth argument is definitely it. When I change the 255 values the white boxes change color, but adjusting the alpha doesn't change it. Aggravating because it worked in previous pygame versions! It must be a bug. (or a cruddy feature)

Comment: @SuperDisk Didn't think it would work, but if you set the fourth argument to the color of the background, it will work (although it won't work on a multicolored background).  If you want to get a transparent background, another thing to try is `None` for the fourth argument, although I'm not sure about that either.  I aggree, it's probably a bug.

Comment: `None` didn't work either. I suppose I'll go look at the plumbing and some diffs here pretty soon and see what's no longer working.

Comment: @SuperDisk I just realized the most obvious solution.  Just set the colorkey to `(255, 255, 255)`.  Duh.

Comment: Brilliant. Put that bit in the actual answer and you'll have an accept. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This most certainly still is a bug though, and should be reported somewhere. :(

Comment: It's not a bug. You either get a transparent or filled color depending on the arguments (aliasing as well as background color) you use. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#Font.render

Comment: @monkey It's a bug. Same exact code worked in the last version of pygame.